# Matplotlib/SNS: plot histogram but with average of another variable on the y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a continuous variable A and a one hot encoded variable B (only 0s and 1s). I want a histogram where A is divided into 10 equal-width bins, and the y-axis variable is the average of B for the observations in each bin. How can I do this with matplotlib/seaborn? Is there another way, perhaps more orthodox, to convey this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.digitize()` can be used to allocate each value of `a` into a corresponding bin. Then, a bar can show the mean of `b` for each of the bins. There need to be 11 bin boundaries to create 10 bins. An epsilon needs to be added to the rightmost boundary to make the maximum value of `a` fall into the 10<sup>th</sup> bin.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 200)
b = np.random.randint(0, 2, 200)
bins = np.linspace(a.min(), a.max() + 1e-12, 11) # 10 bins, so 11 bin boundaries
c = np.digitize(a, bins)
plt.bar(bins[:-1], [np.mean(b[c == i]) for i in range(1, len(bins))],
        width=bins[1] - bins[0], align='edge', fc='turquoise', ec='black')
plt.xticks(bins)
plt.margins(x=0.02) # smaller margins
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]